# Using a Key to stop a timer outside of the jframe

Tags: java, swing

So I'm making a simple AutoClicker just to test myself.  Now I've ran into a small problem.  I am trying to make it so when I use "control + minus" it stops the auto clicker.  Problem is I have to have the jframe focused to do so.  Is there any way I get the key the user touched outside of the jframe?

For example: Your playing cookie clicker and you hit "control and =" to start the auto clicker, then you can stop it while playing cookie clicker by doing "control and +"

My Listener:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class JListener implements ActionListener
 {


  @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if(e.getActionCommand() == "exit") {
        GUIs.frame.dispose();
        AutoClicker.getTimer().cancel();
      } else if(e.getActionCommand() == "start") {



      } else if(e.getActionCommand() == "stop") {
        AutoClicker.getTimer().cancel();
    }

 }
}
```

My GUI:

```
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GUIs
{
  public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("AutoClicker");
   private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

private GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
private int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
private int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();

//Componenets
private static JButton startbutton = new JButton("Start");
private static JLabel autoclick = new JLabel("AutoClicker 2.0");

public void createMainGui() {
    //frame
    frame.setSize(width/2,height/2);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setLocation(width/4, height/4);


    //JPanel
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());

    //JMenu -> Different method
    createJMenu(frame);

    //Initialize Components

    //startbutton.setBounds((frame.getWidth() / 2), (frame.getHeight()), 100, 25);




    //Add components
    panel.add(startbutton);

    frame.add(panel);


    //show frame

    frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            resizeComponents(frame);
        }
    });
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


public static void createJMenu(JFrame fr) {
    //Menu Bar
    JMenuBar jbar = new JMenuBar();


    //Listener -> different class
    JListener l = new JListener();


    //Exit Menu
    JMenu exitmenu = new JMenu("Exit");
    jbar.add(exitmenu);


    //Exit Item
    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    exit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q, Event.CTRL_MASK));
    exit.setActionCommand("exit");
    exit.addActionListener(l);
    exitmenu.add(exit);

    //Options Menu
    JMenu optionsmenu = new JMenu("Options");
    jbar.add(optionsmenu);

    //Start Item
    JMenuItem start = new JMenuItem("Start");
    start.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS, Event.CTRL_MASK));
    start.setActionCommand("start");
    start.addActionListener(l);
    optionsmenu.add(start);

    //Stop Item
    JMenuItem stop = new JMenuItem("Stop");
    stop.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS, Event.CTRL_MASK));
    stop.setActionCommand("stop");
    stop.addActionListener(l);
    optionsmenu.add(stop);





    //set JMenu to frame
    fr.setJMenuBar(jbar);

}

public void resizeComponents(JFrame frame) {
    System.out.println(frame.getHeight());
    startbutton.setBounds((frame.getWidth() / 2) - 50, (int) (frame.getHeight() / 1.5), 100, 25);
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.repaint();
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not using pure Java. You need to use JNA or JNI (I can never remember) to access system level key events.

Comment: @camickr where can I learn more about this? I've never heard of either of those.

Comment: Search the forum or the web. I think JNI stands for "Java Native Interface". Not sure what JNA is short for, but again you can easily search the web.

Comment: `e.getActionCommand() == "exit"` isn't how you should b comparing strings

Comment: Where is `AutoClicker` defined ?  Please post [mcve]